# SELECT query return error on Empty result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using `SELECT` query as a subquery in Query given below...

```
SELECT COUNT (`Notification`.`id`) AS `count`
FROM `listaren_mercury_live`.`notifications` AS `Notification`
WHERE NOT FIND_IN_SET(`Notification`.`id`,(SELECT read_ids FROM read_notifications WHERE user_id = 46))
AND((notisfication_for IN("all","India"))
OR(FIND_IN_SET(46,notification_for))
```

This query working fine when

```
SELECT read_ids FROM read_notifications WHERE user_id = userid)
```

return result like 21,22,23,24

but when this query return empty.

The result id `0` instead of `3`. There are 3 unread notifications for the user; so the result must be `3`

**Problem**

The query gives correct result when internal select query's return like

```
12,42
```

but if query return null then the whole query's result becomes 0.

**Expected Result With Query**

[image: Expected Result]

**Result I'm getting**

[image: Result I'm getting]

I just want if the subquery returns an empty value. Then the query **(Notification.id,(SELECT read_ids FROM read_notifications WHERE user_id) = 46)** result looks like

```
 (`Notification`.`id`,(0))
```

instead of

```
(`Notification`.`id`,())
```

So it will work properly

Please tell me what improvement I need in this.

Thanks

Comment: You really need to show us sample data from your tables.  As a general comment, you should **not** be storing CSV data in your table.  So the real issue is that, whether right or wrong, your data design is wrong.

Comment: Fix your data model.  Storing lists of numbers as a comma-delimited string is simply wrong in a SQL database.

Comment: iam totally with the other comment's here is more info on why you shouldn't store CSV into a database -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Question edited... Is that understandable now...?

Comment: look into MySQL's control flow functions -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
FIND_IN_SET(`Notification`.`id`,(SELECT read_ids FROM read_notifications WHERE user_id = 46))
```

with

```
FIND_IN_SET(`Notification`.`id`,IFNULL((SELECT read_ids FROM read_notifications WHERE user_id = 46), ''))
```

From the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/scalar-subqueries.html), if the subquery result is empty it will return NULL,   and [FIND_IN_SET will return NULL if either argument is NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set), and [NOT NULL is still NULL, as is NULL AND 1, and NULL is equivalent to false](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html). So when the subquery returns NULL, your WHERE condition will fail.

By adding an IFNULL around the subquery result, you can get it to return a value which is valid for FIND_IN_SET, which will allow your query to work as expected.